# What is wrong with the ngModel? I want input box as a component in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I want input box as a component with custom validations that can be injected into this. So that one input component is available to rule the entire project and the validations are so generic that they are at one place and we are able to reutilize the component everywhere.

The code for the input component is as follows:-

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'alt-text-field',
    template: `
    <input 
    #field="ngModel"
    class="form-control"
    [id]="id"
    [name]="name"
    [ngModel]="value"
    (ngModelChange)="onValueChange($event)"
    [placeholder]="placeholder"
    [type]="type"
    minlength="5" maxlength="8"
    required
    > {{field.className}}`
})
export class AltTextFieldComponent {
    /** ID for an element */
    @Input() id: string;

    /** Name of the Text Field Element */
    @Input() name;

    /** Placeholder for the Text Field */
    @Input() placeholder: string;

    /** Type for the Text Field */
    @Input() type: string;

    /** Value for the Text Field */
    @Input() value: String;

    /** Value change to register a change in the value of the component */
    @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<string>();

    /** Method to handle the change in the input field */
    onValueChange(event){
        this.valueChange.emit(event)
    }
}
```

It works fine until I add the `#field="ngModel"` after adding this I am not able to work with the input. It does not print the class name as such.

On the other hand I also need the form to be a component. So that it can be utilized throughout the application.  Please help me in order to understand whether my approach is correct or am I assuming something wrong. As well as if possible please point me to this kind of code.

Comment: Why do you need #field="ngModel" since you've already binded you're <input> with [ngModel]="value" ?

Comment: I think that in order to work you should bind #field with a FormControl object, and I believe ngModel isn't

Comment: @theFreedomBanana to be precise when I try to put in form validations I am getting problem. The moment I wrap it into a parent component the validations disappear. :-/

Comment: Best would be a plunker to reproduce your problem. :)